# jquery validationEngine - error notification flickers before form closed

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I've a simple form here: http://jsfiddle.net/m2qqb/10/

When i hit "close" or "cancel" without filling required fields, error notification near focused input is shown for a few milliseconds.

I know this happens because focus is changed from input to "close" or "cancel" button.

What i want is to keep error notifications while user changes focus between fields other than "close" or "cancel" buttons.

Can i somehow tell validationEngine to ignore specific focuschange events?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the target of an event and ignore it if it was fired by a certain element.

Give the element you cant to ignore a class, eg "ignoreEvent". So your close button will now look like this:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick ignoreEvent">close</span>
```

You then check if the event's target belongs to this class:

```
if(!$(event.target).hasClass()){ doSomething}
else{ignore}
```